# What file is facebook looking for

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, gradle

I'm getting this error when trying to build in Unity or Android Studio

```
        * What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidsdk.modules:shield:unspecified.
     Required by:
         project : > com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:5.15.2
         project : > com.facebook.android:facebook-core:5.15.2
         project : > com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.15.2
         project : > com.facebook.android:facebook-share:5.15.2
         project : > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:5.15.2
```

Here is my gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

// Android Resolver Repos Start
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each { project ->
    project.repositories {
        def unityProjectPath = "file:///C:/Users/joshe/Documents/GitHub/GameDay"
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url (unityProjectPath + "/Assets/Firebase/m2repository") // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:20, Assets/Firebase/Editor/MessagingDependencies.xml:20
        }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
// Android Resolver Repos End
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
    // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
    // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:5.15.2'
    // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:5
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:5.15.2'
    // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
    // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:3
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:5
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    // Assets/Firebase/Editor/MessagingDependencies.xml:15
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:6.9.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:20
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.3.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:4
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/MessagingDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-unity:6.9.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/MessagingDependencies.xml:20
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:4
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-applovin-9.9.2', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-facebook-5.5.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-mintegral-9.13.21-alphab', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-mintegral-9.13.21-common', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-mintegral-9.13.21-interstitial', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-mintegral-9.13.21-interstitialvideo', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-mintegral-9.13.21-mtgdownloads', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-mintegral-9.13.21-mtgjscommon', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-mintegral-9.13.21-mtgnative', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-mintegral-9.13.21-nativeex', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-mintegral-9.13.21-playercommon', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-mintegral-9.13.21-reward', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-mintegral-9.13.21-videocommon', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-mintegral-9.13.21-videojs', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-mytarget-5.4.7', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-ogury-3.0.36', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appodeal-smaato-21.1.3', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-17.2.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-app-unity-6.9.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-common-19.3.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-components-16.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-datatransport-17.0.3', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-encoders-json-16.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-20.0.2', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-interop-17.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-18.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-messaging-20.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-messaging-unity-6.9.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-android-wrapper-7.18.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'NativeShare', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'pollfish-googleplay-5.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation project(':appodeal')
    implementation project(':appodeal-adcolony')
    implementation project(':appodeal-amazon')
    implementation project(':appodeal-chartboost')
    implementation project(':appodeal-inmobi')
    implementation project(':appodeal-ironsource')
    implementation project(':appodeal-mintegral')
    implementation project(':appodeal-startapp')
    implementation project(':appodeal-tapjoy')
    implementation project(':appodeal-unityads')
    implementation project(':appodeal-vungle')
    implementation project(':appodeal-yandex-metrica')
    implementation project(':appodeal-yandex-mobileads')
    implementation project(':Firebase')
}

// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingOptions {
      exclude ('/lib/arm64-v8a/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')
      exclude 'project.properties'
      exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
  }
}
// Android Resolver Exclusions End
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId ''
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
        versionCode 2
        versionName '0.1'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', 'google-services-desktop.json', 'mockup.png']
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('')
            storePassword ''
            keyAlias ''
            keyPassword ''
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
    }

    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}
```

I have no clue why this is happening, i've never seen this particular error before, specifically the 'unspecified' part.

My SDK tools seems to be up to date as well.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated very much.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out facebook updated their dependencies file.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: Updated the Facebook dependencies file. You can find the latest on the github for the unity Facebook SDK.

Comment: Thanks. I landed here because I'm having the same issue in a React Native project. There's an issue on the main SDK repo https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/673 and another on the RN repo https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/701 if anyone else gets stuck on this.